# Grails 3 - Gradle dependecies Mysql Connector

Tags: mysql, gradle, grails-3.0

I have set up a grails app using grails 3.0.9

Now I want to add the mysql connector to bring up an connection to a mysql database.

Therefore I have added an entry to my build.gradle, but the connector is not fetched by gradle.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"
        classpath "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
}

version "0.1"
group "nexttext"

apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong but I get an ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 3):

Add `runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37"` to your dependencies (Right under `runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"`). Then compile it. That should do the trick.

In my Grails 3 project I don't have a classpath to the connector, so I think it is save to remove it there.

Also don't forget to add these lines to your application.yml under your dataSource:

```
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: Ok stange thing ... if I run the app via "grails run-app" from the commandline it is working with 'runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37"' but NOT inside Intellij IDEA EAP 15. Are you using any IDE?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.7. But I downgraded my project from 3.0.6 to 2.5.1, since it has too many problems. It isn't very well (if at all) integrated into the IDE's, and a lot of plugins are causing trouble. While I was working on 3.0.6 I was using the command line to run and compile.

Comment: Intellij said that grails 3 would be supported as of 15 but my experience of the EAP is not that good. And yes adding plugins causes trouble too. It is not possible to add plugins like font-awesome without problems :(

Answer (score 2):

Adding a local gradle installation to Intellij seems to solve the problem. I think that the included gradle-wrapper caused the trouble.

So downloading gradle 2.8 and setting it to use in Settings -> Build... -> Build Tools -> Gradle solved the problem.

Now the mysql connector is showing up under External Libraries
Gradle: mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37

Comment: Thanks for the tip above. The Gradle wrapper is definitely causing this behavior. Works like a charm!

Comment: Same behaviour with gradle 2.11, changed to 2.14.1 (current) + IntelliJ 15.0.2) and worked. Seems a problem with the ssl handshake while downloading the mysql connector jar. Thanks!